# php - check if a string contains a float

Tags: php, string, floating-point

What is the easiest way to check if a string contains a valid float?

For example

```
is_string_float("1") = true
is_string_float("1.234") = true
is_string_float("1.2e3") = true
is_string_float("1b2") = false
is_string_float("aldhjsfb") = false
```

Comment: because that's not what I'm looking for. `is_float("1") = false`

Comment: False because `1` in an integer

Comment: no, because `"1"` is a string, not a float. The same holds for `is_float("1.234")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use built in function [is_float()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php). To test if a variable is a number or a numeric string you must use [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).

Comment: `is_numeric` is what I was looking for

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to know if a string contains a float and ONLY a float you cannot use `is_float()` (wrong type) or `is_numeric()` (returns `true` for a string like `"1"` too) only. I'd use

```
<?php

    function foo(string $string) : bool {
        return is_numeric($string) && strpos($string, '.') !== false;
    }

?>
```

instead.

Comment: `is_float()` is checking the type not whether the value can be coerced to a float - which is what something like `is_numeric()` does but for integers.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can use a couple of functions

out of the box

```
function is_string_float($string) {
    if(is_numeric($string)) {
        $val = $string+0;

        return is_float($val);
    } 
      
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This will error in PHP8 as addition cannot be performed on a string and an int.

Comment: @Harry I'm pretty sure the is_numeric check would ensure that PHP treats the string as an int (or float) before the addition operation is done.

Comment: PHP 8.2 complains only with code similar to `echo "Z" + 0, "\n";`. `echo "1" + 0, "\n";` will print `1` without throwing any exception.

Answer (score -1):

This can easily be achieved by double casting.

```php
/**
 * @param string $text
 * @return bool
 */
function is_string_float(string $text): bool
{
    return $text === (string) (float) $text;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work on a string like "0.000"